# How to perform an operation before throwing an exception in optional.orElseThrow(..)

Tags: java, option-type

Current working code:

```
AppUser user = repository.findByEmail(userName);
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found: " + userName));
```

Need to change something like below but it's not working, giving compilation error:

```
AppUser user = repository.findByEmail(userName)
   .orElseThrow(() -> {
        AuditEvent event = 
                 new AuditEvent(userName, "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE", new HashMap<String, Object>());
        auditPublisher.publish(event);
        new RuntimeException("User not found: " + userName);
});
```

Although I have done work around like below for this but it doesn't seem good way to do this. Please suggest better way if available.

```
Optional<AppUser> userOptional = repository.findByEmail(userName);
AppUser user = userOptional.orElse(null);
if (user == null) {
    AuditEvent event = new AuditEvent(userName, "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE", new HashMap<String, Object>());
    auditPublisher.publish(event);
    throw new RuntimeException("User not found: " + userName);
```

}

Kindly let me know if any other details required to clarify my question.

Comment: You don't `return` the created `RuntimeException` in your modified `orElseThrow`, vtc as typo

Comment: Lambda needs to return not just instantiate

Comment: @Lino thanks to bring out the right point which I was missing. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a return statement in your lambda.

```
AppUser user = repository.findByEmail(userName)
   .orElseThrow(() -> {
        AuditEvent event = 
                 new AuditEvent(userName, "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE", new HashMap<String, Object>());
        auditPublisher.publish(event);
        return new RuntimeException("User not found: " + userName);
});
```